Asymptotic of the integral $\int_0^1 x^{k-1}(1-x)^{l-1}(1-ax)^{\frac{m}{2}}\, dx$
Consider the integral
$$
I(n,a) = \int_0^1 x^{k-1}(1-x)^{l-1}(1-ax)^{\frac{m}{2}}\, dx,
$$
where $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
k+l=n\in\mathbb{N},\quad 0<a<1,\quad m\in\mathbb{N}\quad\mbox{and}\quad m\le \min\{\log k,\log l\}.
$$
Fix $a\in(0,1)$, I want to know the asymptotic of $I(n,a)$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$.
From a book I find a formula which is expressed in hypergeometric function:
$$
I(n,a) = {}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{m}{2},k\,;n\,;a\right) \,\mbox{B}(k,l),
$$
where $\mbox{B}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function and ${}_2 F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function. But I cannot obtain more information. The asymptotic of beta function is easy. But I don't know the hypergeometric function.
The origin question is the asymptotic of this integral:
$$
J(n,u,v) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (u \sin^2\theta+ v\cos^2\theta)^{\frac{m}{2}} (\sin\theta)^{2k-1} (\cos\theta)^{2l-1} \,d\theta,
$$
with $0<u<v\le 1$, while $k,l,m,n$ are as above. By a change of variable I reduce $J(n,u,v)$ to $I(n,a)$. And I am stuck.
Note also that $m$ is extremely small compared to $n$.

Maybe Laplace method is useful.


This might help:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05146

May be this help https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12

How do $k$ and $l$ grow when their sum tends to infinity?

@Amir We need to consider every case.

@Amir Assume $k>l$, I guess essentially there are two cases (i) $l<\log(k)$, (ii) $\log(k)<l<k$.

As you mention, Laplace’s method can help. Rewrite this as
$$ \int_{[0,1]} h(x) e^{n f(x)} \mathrm d x $$
with $h(x) = \frac{(1-ax)^{m/2}}{x(1-x)}$ and $f(x) = \alpha \ln x + (1-\alpha)\ln (1-x)$, where $k = \alpha n$. The function $f$ has a unique critical point $x_0$ where
$$ f’(x_0) = \frac\alpha{x_0} - \frac{1-\alpha}{1-x_0} = 0 $$
so we easily see that $x_0 = \alpha$, and
$$ f"(\alpha) = - \alpha^{-1} - (1-\alpha)^{-1} < 0 . $$
We will assume for simplicity that $m$ and $\alpha$ are constant. Of course this is not the case: $\alpha$ has to be of the form $k/n$ which must take different values as $n$ grows if you enforce that $k\in\mathbb N$ (though you don’t have to), and you might be interested in the case where $m$ increases with $n$. The advantage of this assumption is that the conclusions are easier. It should be possible, with sufficient care given to the estimates, to handle the case where $\alpha$ and $m$ can depend on $n$.
Laplace’s method then gives you that this is asymptotically equivalent to
$$ \frac{(1-a\alpha)^{m/2}}{\alpha(1-\alpha)} e^{n (\alpha \ln \alpha + (1-\alpha)\ln(1-\alpha))} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n(\alpha^{-1}+(1-\alpha)^{-1})}} . $$
Summing things up, you would thus get an asymptotic (although you would have to specify the dependency of $k$ and $m$ on $n$ to make it rigorous!) of the form
$$ n^{1-m/2} \frac{(n-ak)^{m/2}}{k(n-k)} e^{n \phi(k/n)} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{k^{-1}+(n-k)^{-1}}}  $$
with $\phi(x) = x\ln x + (1-x) \ln (1-x)$.
The next challenge is, of course, to control the error you are doing when comparing your expression with this asymptotic. The best way to proceed is then to look at the proof, so that you can reach the degree of precision that you desire.

Thanks! I worry the case $\alpha\approx 0$. If we using Laplace method, the interval which gives main contribution of the integral maybe too short?

@cbi $\alpha \to 0$ is the case when the saddle is coalescing with the endpoint. An asymptotics that is uniformly valid for $\alpha \ge 0$ can be derived using Bleistein’s method.

@Gary  Can I find the higher dimension version of this argument?
